# Running an SBT Command Line Application gets confused about Scala Version

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to follow the (outdated) instructions for building a command line application in SBT [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Applications.html), but I run into problems when I try and run the published application.

My JAR is published to

`~/.ivy2/local/org.caoilte/test_2.10/0.1-SNAPSHOT/poms/test_2.10.jar`

When I try and run it via `sbt @test.build.properties` using the following configuration (excerpt from `test.build.properties`)

```
[scala]
  version: 2.10
```

it finds my JAR correctly but fails to find Scala

```
module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10
```

However, if I use the following in my `test.build.properties`

```
[scala]
  version: 2.10.4
```

it fails to find my JAR

```
module not found: org.caoilte#test_2.10.4;0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

It seems likely that this was a problem introduced in SBT 0.13.0 that the Command Line Application documentation was not updated to include a workaround for. (The documentation also includes invalid initialGlobalLogging code and uses very old versions of SBT/Scala - I wish we could still use the SBT mailing list to discuss problems like this).

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I was somehow running SBT 0.13.2. When I upgraded to 0.13.7 this problem went away, suggesting that it is a bug that was fixed.